# Define $f(x) = mx+b, \forall x$ and for fixed constants $m$ and $b$. Prove that the function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

I still have trouble with these epsilon delta proofs. Would we pick $\frac{\epsilon}{m}$? I achieved this by taking the abs value of $f(x)-f(y)$ and then dividing by $m$.

Answer (score 5):

Fix an $\epsilon>0$ now we need to find a $\delta>0$ that works for such $\epsilon>0$ and that $\delta>0$ never changes.

We do things background 
$$|f(x) - f(y)| = |m(x - y)| < \epsilon \iff|x - y| < \frac{\epsilon}{|m|}. $$ Now pick $\delta := \frac{\epsilon}{|m|}$ and verify this indeed  works.

Here is the work:
$$|x - y| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(y)|=|m||(x - y)|<|m|\delta=|m|(\epsilon/|m|)=\epsilon,$$ and you are done !

Comment: $|m||x-y|\not >|m(x-y)|$...

Comment: So the absolute value of m, in the denominator of epsilon is necessary correct?

Comment: |m(x - y)| = |m| |x - y| is correct and the result follows from it as I demonstrated.

Comment: |m(x - y)| = |m| |x - y| @user259137 I just added a bigger than inequality instead of equality by accident. If you have any question let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Well, let's check:

Pick any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and we get:

$$|f(x) - f(x \pm \varepsilon/m)| = |mx + b - mx \pm \varepsilon - b| = |\pm \varepsilon| = \varepsilon $$

And so as desired, if we are within $\delta = \varepsilon/m$ distance in the inputs, then we will be within $\varepsilon$ distance in the outputs.  Of course, the $\delta$ isn't pulled out of a hat.  It looks like you had the right idea in finding it, and you'll find more detail in that regard in Karim's post.

You're good to go.

Answer (score 2):

A more "principled" way to prove this might be to observe that:

- $f(x) = x$ is uniformly continuous;
- $f(x) = c$ is uniformly continuous for any constant $c$;
- If $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous and $c$ is a constant, then $c f(x)$ is uniformly continuous;
- If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are uniformly continuous, then $f(x) + g(x)$ is uniformly continuous.

---

If anyone is interested, we can also prove this using **nonstandard analysis**:

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_calculus#Uniform_continuity),
we need to show that for hyperreal numbers $x,y$, if $x \approx y$, then $f(x) \approx f(y)$.
So let $y = x + \epsilon$ with $\epsilon$ infinitesimal, and we have
\begin{align*}
f(y) - f(x) &= f(x + \epsilon) - f(x) \\
&= \big[m(x + \epsilon)\big] + b - \big[mx + b\big] \\
&= m\epsilon \\
&\approx 0,
\end{align*}
since $\epsilon$ is infinitesimal and $m$ is finite.

Comment: Explain the downvote???

Comment: don't count on it, downvoters prefer to hide in the shadows. No basic courtesy nor etiquette nor communication skills keep them there. I have received plenty myself.

Comment: @Gary: If you really think 'courtesy' and 'etiquette' and 'communication skills' require that votes need to be matched to comments, you should worry first about the much bigger pool of unexplained upvotes.

Comment: @Hurkyl: As you can see by my score, I have not had many unexplained upvotes. I had had plenty of downvotes, though.

Comment: @Hurkyl: Actually, the problem I see with anonymous downvotes is the lack of feedback. It is not clear what , if anything may be wrong with the post. An up vote is clear: the post is correct, well-explained, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You want to fix $\epsilon $ so that $$|f(c)-f(d)|=|m(c-d)| < \epsilon $$

When $|c-d| < \delta$ for a fixed $\delta$. Then you can use $|c-d|<....$

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?